# What to do with unpushed git commits after mvn release:perform

Tags: git, maven, github

I did a mvn release:prepare followed by a release:perform. Everything went well and my new library was uploaded to the release repo and there are two new commits in my github remote repo:

1. One for the 1.0 release version(with message [maven-release-plugin] prepare release 1.0-RELEASE)
2. And the other changes to the pom to update to the 1.1-SNAPSHOT version(with message
   [maven-release-plugin] prepare for next development iteration)

   as expected. However, in my local git repo I see two unpushed commits with the exact same messages and exact diffs. I would have expected these commits to have been pushed to the remote branch. Why is this and what should I do with these unpushed commits? Should I just revert them back since all changes seem to be present in the remote repo anyway?

Comment: I would first try to find out why you have these additional local commits that have not been pushed. Somehow the commits were pushed to the remote, otherwise you wouldn't see them there - try to go through the Maven logs to find out which step pushed them.

Comment: What happens if you try to pull ? Also, if you decide to cancel your local commits use reset not revert as revert will undo the work on the remote repository as well !